# Consulta java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, select, sql

Quiero ejecutar un select y copiar cada valor devuelto en un JTextField. He ido comprobando según escribía, pero al llegar al método getString del ResultSet me da error y no veo dónde está el fallo.
¿Cuál es la forma correcta de leer el resultado de un select?

```
public ResultSet consulta(String query) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("La consulta se ha completado con éxito");

        System.out.println(rs.getString("dni"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("nombre"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("matamaticas"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("ingles"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("lengua"));
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        rs = null;
        System.out.println("La consulta ha sido interrumpida");
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ResultSet inicia apuntando a una posición antes del primer registro. Para recorrer los registros hay que llamar al método `next()` del ResultSet. El método `next()` devuelve verdadero si hay otro registro y falso si no lo hay. Si el ResultSet está vacío no entra en el while:

```
while(rs.next()){
  System.out.println(rs.getString("dni"));
}
```

Comment: ¿Entonces el problema que me daba es porque seguía realizando la instrucción aunque no quedasen registros?

Comment: No, según tu código el problema es que el ResultSet tiene su cursor posicionado antes de la primera fila, entonces si se hace un `getString()` da error porque ahí no hay datos. El método `next()` pone el cursor en la primera fila y cada vez que se llama sigue avanzando las filas.